# Convert time range into minutes formula

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, date-time

I need a formula that will convert time into minutes and round up 30 sec to 1 minute.

Example: change `7:58:31` (hr:min:sec) to 479 minutes  or `08:31:29` to 511 minutes.  The first example adds 1 minute to total because 31 seconds is over half a minute.

Comment: Is mysql query an acceptable solution ?

Comment: We'll need more information, as right now this isn't much of a question.  What kind of formula are you looking for?  How/where are you reading the time from?  Are you looking for an answer in a scripting language?  For Excel?  What have you tried already?  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: reading from a cell that contains imported data that is in the format of hh:mm:ss ex: F14 contains [01:02:45] and I would like to convert it to mm or F70 [63] which is the conversion to minutes in this example or 60*1+3 because 45 sec is close to 1 minute

Comment: reading from a cell indicates a spreadsheet, but we're still stuck with not knowing if this is Excel 97, excel 2010, lotus 1-2-3, borland quattro, google docs, or some other spreadsheet. I could be completely wrong, and you're trying to talk to prisoners, and `prison population` should be the tag :)

Comment: something like this =((HOUR(G11)*60)+MINUTE(G11)+(SECOND(G11)/60))

Comment: know how I would use this calculation in a way that would not have a decimal - automatically round to highest without decimal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1440<sup>1</sup> is the magic number in this case

using `ROUND` to round up/down will give you the resolution.
With your time in A1, `=ROUND(A1*1440,0)` will get you the number of minutes

with your calculation of `=((HOUR(G11)*60)+MINUTE(G11)+(SECOND(G11)/60))`, changing to `=((HOUR(G11)*60)+MINUTE(G11)+IF(SECOND(G11)<30,0,1))` would remove the decimal

<sup>1</sup> 1440 is simply 24 *hours* * 60 *minutes*

Comment: (+1) You don't really need the Round.  Just format the cell as a number with 0 decimal places and it should round on its own.

Comment: anyone know how I would use this calculation in a way that would not have a decimal - automatically round to highest without decimal =((HOUR(G11)*60)+MINUTE(G11)+(SECOND(G11)/60))

Comment: updated answer!

Comment: Thank you Sean, that works great. can you modify to copy to another sheet? say I calculate the formula from imported sheet1 to Thursday / same book

Comment: References to another sheet are done using `!` - e.g G1 on sheet1 will be `sheet1!G1`. If the sheet name has spaces then surround it with quotes. G1 on My Sheet would be `'My Sheet'!G1`

Comment: I need a script to use this formula on a sheet to get "summery and breaks"  for a group of agents; agent 1 
summery 01:02:45
() 8/26/2012 
Break_1000 00:34:44
Not_Ready_Default_Reason_Code 00:28:01
daily 8/26/2012 01:02:45
Agent: 01:02:45
agent 2 
Summary: 00:30:22
() 8/26/2012 
Not_Ready_Default_Reason_Code 00:04:29
Break_1000 00:25:53
daily 8/26/2012 00:30:22
Agent: 00:30:22
agent 3 
Summary: 00:32:30
() 8/26/2012 
Not_Ready_Default_Reason_Code 00:00:03
Break_1000 00:29:55
Personal_4000 00:02:32
daily 8/26/2012 00:32:30
Agent: 00:32:30